# PostGIS not using spatial index despite a pretty simple case

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap

I have some spatial data from OpenStreetMap inside my PostgreSQL database.
I am trying to force a situation where it would use a spatial index (which exists and was created on the the_geog field, which is a geometry). It's not like PostgreSQL **never** uses spatial indexes in my queries, but many times it doesn't, opting for a Parallel Seq Scan. And this is a scenario where, according to my limited knowledge, it'd be very good to use an index (we have a super strict filtering which returns one point!).

```
SELECT the_geog FROM points
WHERE the_geog=CAST('0101000020E61000000B3087383109354014645F0DAB244A40' AS geometry)
```

What I did (and didn't work):

- ANALYZE points
- add LIMIT 1 at the end of query

What the execution plan on the query above looks like:

```
"Gather  (cost=1000.00..33369.36 rows=1169 width=32)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on points  (cost=0.00..32252.46 rows=487 width=32)"
"        Filter: (the_geog = '0101000020E61000000B3087383109354014645F0DAB244A40'::geometry)"
```

Can someone explain this to me? I'm not even dead-set on using the index, but I'd really need to know why PostgreSQL's optimizer refrains from using it.

Bonus question, if I may of course - with standard OSM data format, is there any reason **not to** create an additional index on osm_id, if I'm using it in WHERE clauses sometimes?

Comment: If I have understood right the spatial index does not actually index the geometries but the bounding boxes of the geometries. I would try using ST_Equals instead of direct comparison of geometries. Maybe http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2021/05/indexes-and-queries.html would give you more ideas.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. "Bonus" questions will result in closure for lack of *focus*. Note that an equivalence test is an awful way to compare geometries, and can't use an index.

Comment: Thank you both for your useful suggestions and links :) That ST_Equals was the answer I was seeking